# What does the regex string "\\p{Cntrl}" match in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I think it's matching all control characters (not sure what "all" might be) but I can't be certain, nor can I find it in any documentation other than some musings in a Perl forum. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> `\p{Cntrl}`   A control character: `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]`

That is, it matches any character with hexadecimal value 00 through 1F or 7F.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) on control characters lists each character and what it's used for if you're interested.

Answer (score 7):

`\p{name}` matches a Unicode character class; consult the appropriate Unicode spec to see what code points are in the class.  [Here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/character_classes_named.shtml) is a discussion specific to the Java regex engine (`Cntrl` being one of the examples `Any ASCII control character in the range 0-127. This effectively means characters 0-31 and 127.`), although the same thing applies to many other regex engines.